# Find out the logged in users in ADempiere

Tags: erp, adempiere

I have deployed the ADempiere in a server and provide the jnlp based client installation to the users in the network. How can I find out the users accessing the server at a time. Is there any audit option or cange log features. 
When a client accessing the server, it marks as

```
 12:52:37,547 INFO  [[/admin]] Request: /admin/adempiere.jnlp
 12:52:37,555 INFO  [[/admin]] User-Agent: JNLP/6.0 javaws/1.6.0_30
 (b12) Java/1.6.0_30 12:52:37,565 INFO  [[/admin]] Resource returned:/adempiere.jnlp
```

How can I identify the users accessing the service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Querying the `AD_Session` Table, you can get the no of users logged into the system.

You will get active/inactive connections based on the `processed` column.

For getting active users in the system :-

```
SELECT AD_Org_ID, AD_Role_ID, remote_addr, remote_host, processed, logindate, 
created as "login date with time",  createdby As AD_User_ID FROM AD_Session 
WHERE Processed='N' AND logindate >  current_date-1;
```

(you can update the above sql as your wish)

Answer (score 0):

use this Query for update Session in

update  AD_Session set Processed='Y' where HERE Processed='N' AND logindate >  current_date-1;